# antd v4 - Steps and Form

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am new to React and i am playing around with ant design. I need to build a multi-step form where each step has a couple of fields and the final step will have a submit button. This would use useForm hook from antd. I would prefer not to use any other plugins like antd-form-builder etc.

The issue i am facing is that in the multi-step form, at the last step, when i press submit the form data for last step is available and data for previous steps is not available. I reckon this could be because the step is being replaced in DOM when i move to "next" step.

Is there any simpler way to obtain the data from all forms at the last step ?

I have prepared a codesandbox for the sample.. Refer the console after submitting.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mcnulty-or8jw

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it's because your steps are destroyed when you're not showing them in the DOM.

Add a step to your steps array like this:

```
const steps = [
    {
      step: 1,
      title: "Step1",
      content: <Step1Form />
    },
    {
      step: 2,
      title: "Step2",
      content: <Step2Form />
    }
];
```

Then define a new class in your css file:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Lastly, in your `StepPanel.js` file change the rendering approach of steps to this. We're going to render all of steps:

```
{props.steps.map((item) => (
    <div
      className={`steps-content ${
        item.step !== activeStep + 1 && "hidden"
      }`}
    >
      {item.content}
    </div>
))}
```

As you can see, we are checking every step if its step number is equal to the currently active step. You can change a forked version of your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-bas-fw9ij?file=/src/styles.css:95-124).

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot @Hossein Ahmadi..! Thanks for the explanation and making it crystal clear ! :) The answer is accepted !

Comment: Great answer. How would you do form validation for each step using this setup when clicking on "Next" or "Continue" button?

Comment: @d48 Thanks. You can provide a `name` for every step or use the `title` property and pass it to `onClick`. Then do the validation based on the step.

Comment: @HosseinAhmadi thank you. In the codesandbox example linked, would the `stepForm` object need to be passed down through a prop to the <StepPanel /> component or can <StepPanel /> get access to thee form object a different way?

Comment: I guess the other thing too consider is how to dynamically only validate the form fields that are not hidden at each step but still submit in its entirety on final submit.

Comment: @d48 We're passing whole steps array meaning you have access to the object in your `map`

Comment: @HosseinAhmadi thanks. I was able to address validation per step with consolidating field values at each step and submitting on the final step.

Comment: This answer is so dope! Thx @HosseinAhmadi

Answer (score 17):

Although the above answer works, I prefer not to use CSS to hide and show steps as it defeats the purpose of the way React only renders the required components.

Antd actually has a built-in way of handling this in their documentation. All you need to do is update the below code.

`const formData = form.getFieldsValue();`

to

`const formData = form.getFieldsValue(true);`

This will return the value of all the fields not just the hidden ones see their documentation: https://ant.design/components/form/#API;

Comment: This is definitely the right way of doing it, deserves more upvotes!

Comment: This is awesome I was struggling because form not showing all fields value , stuck for hours. Thanks man.