# Not able to access data of second form in Steps antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am adding 2 different forms in antd steps inside a modal and validating individual form. Created 2 instance for both forms. Not able to get the data of form in second step.

****** Code *******

```
import { React, FC } from "react";

const Form = () => {
  const [Form1] = useForm();
  const [Form2] = useForm();

  const checkFormValidations = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await realtorForm1.validateFields();
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      message.error(e.message.data);
    }
  };

  const checkForm2Validations = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await realtorForm2.validateFields();
      // I am not getting this data
      // Calling API to Add Data
    } catch (e) {
      message.error(e.message.data);
    }
  };

  const steps = [
    {
      key: 1,
      title: "First",
      content: (
        <Form
          form={Form1}
          initialValues={DataProps}
          validateTrigger="onBlur"
        ></Form>
      ),
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      title: "Second",
      content: (
        <Form
          form={Form2}
          initialValues={DataProps}
          validateTrigger="onBlur"
        ></Form>
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Modal>
      <Steps current={current} items={items} />
      <div style={contentStyle}>{steps[current].content}</div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        {current < steps.length - 1 && (
          <BaseButton type="primary" onClick={() => checkFormValidations()}>
            Next
          </BaseButton>
        )}
        {current > 0 && (
          <BaseButton style={{ margin: "0 8px" }} onClick={() => prev()}>
            Previous
          </BaseButton>
        )}
        {current === steps.length - 1 && (
          <BaseButton type="primary" onClick={() => checkForm2Validations()}>
            Submit
          </BaseButton>
        )}
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

`

When I moved the form to the first step, I got the data for that form.

It seems like an issue with hydration while the steps are getting added to the modal.

Comment: How did you get the form data? I don't see the code.

Comment: I am adding the code within a few minutes. Thank you for the response. @LinDu

Comment: I got the solution.

Sharing the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807887/antd-v4-steps-and-form